# Certificate not trusted of SSL website in Android with custom TrustManager

Tags: android, security, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

My app connects to my own website (which uses a valid Let's encrypt certificate) via https, but Android does not trust the certificate. It gives this exception:

```
07-21 13:26:56.161 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:247)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1058)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.abyx.loyalty.tasks.LogoTask.downloadLogo(LogoTask.java:140)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.abyx.loyalty.tasks.LogoTask.doInBackground(LogoTask.java:110)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.abyx.loyalty.tasks.LogoTask.doInBackground(LogoTask.java:63)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
07-21 13:26:56.162 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     ... 21 more
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-21 13:26:56.163 9679-9679/com.abyx.loyalty W/System.err:     ... 31 more
```

I followed the official Android guide on fixing this issue by accepting my own certificate (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html), but the issue remains.

Now, I've tried to debug this issue and printed out the certificate that Android extracts from my website and the one that I hand to it, but they are identical! How can it still complain and not trust the certificate?

This is my code:

```
public String getJSON(String store, Context context) throws IOException, LogoNotFoundException {
        try {
            // Load CAs from an InputStream
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.abyx));
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            store = URLEncoder.encode(store, "UTF-8");
            String response;
            URL url = new URL("https://www.abyx.be/loyalty/public/logo/" + URLEncoder.encode(store, "utf-8"));
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            connection.connect();
            Certificate[] certificates = connection.getServerCertificates();
            for (Certificate cert: certificates) {
                System.out.println(cert);
            }
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            } else if (statusCode == 404) {
                throw new LogoNotFoundException();
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unable to connect to Loyalty API!");
            }
            return response;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | CertificateException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
```

This is the website I'm trying to connect to: https://abyx.be

Any thoughts on what I could have done wrong?

---

This is my certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And this is the certificate decoded using `openssl x509`.

```
$ openssl x509 -in temp.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:63:20:83:cd:26:7a:fb:af:8b:e9:75:41:c2:ff:3e:96:2a
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul  8 23:07:00 2017 GMT
            Not After : Oct  6 23:07:00 2017 GMT
        Subject: CN=abyx.be
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c3:09:c4:e8:80:35:54:f1:b8:71:df:00:8c:4a:
                    6d:eb:86:0c:f9:9a:13:f6:99:aa:b7:08:08:77:b1:
                    b3:fc:52:0e:11:04:de:7b:8a:bc:04:97:1c:48:01:
                    28:58:6c:61:17:bf:66:d6:db:46:fa:38:09:25:c9:
                    34:6b:2a:bd:e5:37:9e:6f:fc:9f:01:4d:37:a2:1c:
                    82:10:5e:c6:85:4c:52:cf:4c:2e:e8:39:49:dc:72:
                    c4:91:82:b6:11:be:92:db:91:67:82:8e:78:c0:c0:
                    f2:69:ca:2f:44:2c:1e:d9:87:44:e6:1b:5d:a2:a2:
                    58:17:39:9b:0a:85:fd:03:ed:88:44:20:23:98:7f:
                    a8:5d:97:fb:b0:4b:a2:4a:f0:cc:e3:50:00:ed:dc:
                    96:f6:0e:e8:07:28:2f:bd:19:96:ea:5b:ed:b7:de:
                    0a:6b:6a:df:b9:21:a2:bf:62:a2:79:95:c8:48:6d:
                    03:e7:7a:0d:01:0c:2c:2e:b8:1b:61:9c:09:a2:43:
                    fc:9f:3f:32:73:e5:47:57:2b:25:f1:6c:46:e1:d4:
                    b2:55:c8:c4:93:3a:a8:ad:6e:0f:9a:af:36:29:20:
                    c3:30:e2:5e:a6:f9:73:0a:37:a2:6b:d0:11:91:8b:
                    36:91:f1:6b:ed:2d:6f:d5:28:d7:25:6d:ae:29:82:
                    40:6e:63:10:dc:97:a5:2e:4f:59:92:29:08:d0:45:
                    30:f1:79:42:a5:4c:6f:25:7e:df:5d:70:30:48:9f:
                    42:ab:05:b4:df:0e:13:a4:d0:5a:7c:d0:50:11:79:
                    e1:a7:9c:f5:d0:ed:02:fa:b9:42:a1:62:41:64:ea:
                    c9:0c:ca:80:50:f1:aa:8e:a1:4e:4a:40:a3:2a:c1:
                    7c:4c:bb:e6:61:c5:49:87:e3:90:b3:4c:6a:6f:26:
                    01:d6:48:66:bb:f9:c9:05:41:85:df:a6:8f:f6:8b:
                    01:6e:4b:55:15:e6:c7:cc:fa:06:c6:76:73:d7:59:
                    13:57:b7:ca:a1:9f:71:9c:55:fc:a1:9f:70:59:5e:
                    2f:c8:06:a1:c0:7b:b1:65:c7:65:18:17:61:cf:ea:
                    2f:bf:8e:0c:8c:97:ae:b3:a7:2e:58:d6:ce:4e:65:
                    68:16:0f:8a:99:2f:f1:3f:27:c0:e3:d6:32:c7:67:
                    71:4e:9c:ce:d8:cc:7b:34:88:52:2b:9b:d7:5d:fd:
                    fe:84:f3:6d:8d:ae:cb:2a:82:46:67:ba:19:29:40:
                    e5:20:41:57:6e:5d:70:90:bf:c7:6c:65:c8:ad:bc:
                    58:e3:2f:df:87:ea:3c:0d:91:a1:38:e5:04:46:84:
                    31:39:bf:b4:0f:36:5b:de:b6:6a:99:b9:56:5f:47:
                    09:31:0b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                3C:7E:64:F4:E9:52:7A:B4:F3:5F:8C:B9:B1:9F:08:D7:3A:40:69:C9
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:A8:4A:6A:63:04:7D:DD:BA:E6:D1:39:B7:A6:45:65:EF:F3:A8:EC:A1

            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:abyx.be, DNS:www.abyx.be
            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1
                  CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: This Certificate may only be relied upon by Relying Parties and only in accordance with the Certificate Policy found at https://letsencrypt.org/repository/

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         53:04:9b:32:10:10:e0:bb:0e:14:3a:5c:00:3c:aa:6f:e1:1e:
         b9:94:19:a6:d0:08:14:20:ec:c1:13:c8:8d:7b:91:5e:1d:78:
         22:c9:86:fd:77:e0:8d:98:85:1a:1c:86:c0:43:4c:e8:ad:0c:
         7e:54:c1:b5:09:40:10:05:8a:44:d0:b3:e3:64:1d:7d:fa:99:
         64:5c:78:59:ee:ca:d7:6c:2a:d7:97:85:b2:27:7f:44:c7:11:
         e9:b6:d0:b1:22:9a:33:51:b4:b5:28:d6:24:c4:41:c5:11:97:
         a5:28:8a:2c:b8:2d:13:84:8d:c2:98:7b:1f:83:c7:4d:44:0f:
         d8:b7:f3:fe:55:53:60:e3:8b:d7:b8:11:b8:46:87:27:7e:e4:
         64:0d:ac:bd:e2:5e:d7:47:8c:b4:fe:37:48:f5:9b:0d:cf:ff:
         65:e9:f4:0f:32:6b:c2:56:63:1e:ec:e5:f0:67:1a:ae:82:39:
         f0:db:29:7d:8d:99:cb:a1:64:e5:e9:a6:a9:f8:ad:65:ae:90:
         b4:b3:92:0b:31:af:0a:3b:81:1a:96:44:6c:bd:a4:95:95:c4:
         1f:10:54:d1:89:ea:1c:42:ea:10:5c:dd:46:36:76:7e:d9:1f:
         c7:5a:dc:ce:db:cb:6a:63:b3:29:83:3a:4e:df:5a:35:13:47:
         fe:1f:f5:2e
```

Comment: You have error at Apache server config, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.abyx.be&s=185.182.56.117&latest says `server's certificate chain is incomplete`

Comment: Thanks! I've changed something to the server configuration and it does work now. Something was indeed wrong with the chain.

Comment: Posted comment as answer, now you can mark question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error at Apache server config, [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.abyx.be&s=185.182.56.117&latest) says server's certificate chain is incomplete.

Server config must contain these lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/chain.pem
```

Third line is important. It gives full certificate chain for checking to client.

Comment: This answer leaves a lot to be desired. Brace for downvotes. To avoid them, you should probably specify what he needs in the chain sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is **fixing the server chain configuration** as explained by @DeKaNszn. After that, no extra client code should be needed.

In case you don't have access / your admin is **not able to do this**, the following code worked fine for me. It required to read the actual certificate and provide it to the `TrustManager`. Thought I'll add my solution in case someone else is looking for this kind of solution.

The following code creates the `TrustManager` and provides it to the `SocketFactory`. I used **okHttp** with its `OkHttpClient.Builder`.

The trick that solved it for me, was to set both `SocketFactory` AND `TrustManager` to be custom.

Comparing with the usage with the `HttpsURLConnection` in the original question it looks very similar, so it might be just one line that was forgotten.

```
private fun updateSslSocketFactory(httpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder)
{
    val trustManagers: Array<out TrustManager> = getKeyStoreTrustManager()

    if (trustManagers.size != 1 || trustManagers[0] !is X509TrustManager)
    {
        throw IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers))
    }
    val trustManager = trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    val protocol = "TLS"
    val socketFactory = getSocketFactory(protocol, trustManagers)

    // Update okHttp clientBuilder to use our SocketFactory AND TrustManager
    httpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(socketFactory, trustManager)
}


private fun getKeyStoreTrustManager(): Array<out TrustManager>
{
    val keyStore = ConnectionUtils.instance.readStore() // See next section

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    val tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
    val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
    tmf.init(keyStore)

    return tmf.trustManagers
}


private fun getSocketFactory(protocol: String, trustManagers: Array<out TrustManager>?): SSLSocketFactory
{
    val context = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol)
    context.init(null, trustManagers, null)
    return context.socketFactory
}
```

Kotlin string and functions related to reading the certificate and create a `KeyStore` object. I've put this in an extra singleton `ConnectionUtils` for readability:

```
private val cert: String = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n [...]" // Your full certificate content here


fun readStore(): KeyStore
{
    val cert: Certificate = getCa()

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)

    // NOTE: No password for now:
    keyStore.load(null, null)
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", cert)

    return keyStore
}

private fun getCa(): Certificate
{
    // Load CAs from an InputStream
    val caInput = cert.byteInputStream(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    val cert: Certificate
    try
    {
        cert = cf.generateCertificate(caInput)
        Timber.d("Pvlse Cert: %s till %s", (cert as X509Certificate).subjectDN, cert.notAfter)
    } finally
    {
        caInput.close()
    }
    return cert
}
```

Saving your certificate as a string in a class might not be ideal, but at least it's not an obvious file in your apk either and much quicker to process the short text too. So I decided on this route when setting up a connection to an internal developer api where the certificate chain fix wasn't set up correctly.